# Protractor 2.2 not listing outstanding callings when not able to sync with page

Tags: protractor

Protractor 2.2 notes states that protractor will now start listing the outstanding $http and $timeout calls when it is not able to sync with page within the given time limit.

However, I do not see the calls listed in the console when protractor states it could not sync with the page.

Is there a logging flag to turn this on? Anyone else seeing this logging behavior working?

Protractor 2.2 + cucumberJS 0.5.2

As one example of when I receive the error: when I navigate the browser to a login page and the following step executed...

```
this.Then(/^I should see the login page$/, function () {
    browser.wait(EC.titleContains('Welcome'), 30000);
    return expect(browser.getTitle()).to.eventually.contain('Welcome');
  });
```

I got this error (with the absense of a log of outstanding calls):

Then I should see the login page                                                                         # test/e2e/features/framework/branding_groups.feature:174
      Timed out waiting for Protractor to synchronize with the page after 60 seconds. Please see https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/faq.md

Comment: Are you sure if there are outstanding $http or $timeout calls in your case?

Comment: My understanding is that protractor does not provide this "Protractor failed to sync with page after 60 seconds" type error if there are not outstanding $http and $timeout calls. Am I wrong in this understanding?

Comment: @JosephBittman could you please post the code part that's throwing an error, i have this problem sometimes, and it's not always outstanding $http and $timeout.

Comment: @vrachlin, I have added an example step that is failing to the post.

Comment: hi, please try to add this in the beggining:
`beforeEach(function() {
    ptor = protractor.getInstance();
    ptor.ignoreSynchronization = true;
  });`
if it fixes the problem, it's a bug in p-tor synchronization.

Comment: @vrachlin I think there may be a misunderstanding. If we turn angular sync off, yes the script will continue because it is no longer bound to wait for the page to fully load - but that isn't a bug in the sync code; it is expected behavior if an outstanding call has not resolved. The reason for this stack overflow question is to determine if anyone has gotten the outstanding calls to be logged by protractor 2.2 when it hits its timeout.